# How is a contract determined to be ERC20 compliant?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20

How is it exactly determined whether a contract is ERC20 compliant and who determines it? After reading [Do I have to implement ERC20 signature as separate contract and use inheritance?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28066/do-i-have-to-implement-erc20-signature-as-separate-contract-and-use-inheritance) and some googling, I have some ideas.

1) Who decides whether a contract is ERC20 compliant? Is it just the one who wants to use it (exchange, wallet, ...)?

2) How do you determine whether a contract is ERC20 compliant? My current understanding is that all you need is to have the right function signatures (right function hashes). So it doesn't exactly *have* to inherit (implement) from an ERC20 interface. Is that correct?

3) If the answer to the second question is "yes", is it ok to add for example `payable` modifier to some of the functions (as I've understood, it wouldn't change the hash of the function)?

If the answer to question 2 and 3 is "yes", then the following would be a valid implementation of ERC20 standard (assuming the rest of the functions are implemented also):

```
contract A {
  ...
  function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public payable returns (bool success) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wasn't a standard to determine if a contract support an interface at the time ERC20 was conceived (*).

Some block explorers and wallets can make verifications, for example for a ERC20 contracts they can verify if the public functions are available and return something useful, ie `symbol`, `name`, `decimals`, etc.

A block explorer that support contract verification can check the ABI for other methods to also be present, ie `transfer`, `approve`, etc.

That obviously is not enough, a contract that always throws, return false, or zero (depending on the function) can still comply with the [EIP20 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md).

(*) There's now [EIP 165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165) that allows to query a contract for supported interfaces.

Comment: So basically everyone decides for themselves whether they 'accept' something to be ERC20 compliant, right?

Comment: That is the more common approach, if a contract support the minimum functionality expected of an ERC20 is it considered an ERC20.

Comment: `There's no standard to determine if a contract support an interface. `

There is in fact ERC-165, https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-165.md

Answer (score 1):

To add further information about this issue, need to check if proper events are emitted.

Looking at ABI: https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0x93ed3fbe21207ec2e8f2d3c3de6e058cb73bc04d

The ABI does not show `emit`'ted events.

So I think the **MANUAL PROCESS** is required.

Note that some popular ERC20-like tokens such as Binance (pre swap) and Golem are not fully ERC20.