# How to check if the address is an ERC20 contract?

Tags: web3js, web3js-v1.x

edit) VM execution error was a bug on Web3, confirmed my code works fine.

I am trying to fetch random addresses from blockchain and trying to categorize them if it is an ERC20 contract address or not.

I've tried with web3.eth.call to check if the contract has a method `totalSupply()` but there was no success on that thing, with the single address it works fine however at the production stage it returns an odd `(node:10722) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: VM execution error.`

Referring related documents or codes wouldn't help with me unless with web3 1.0.

Here is my code that doesn't work

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));

var ABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];

var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, "0x085b0fdf115aa9e16ae1bddd396ce1f993c52220");

async function checkAddress() {
  var call = await web3.eth.call({ to: "0x085fb4f24031eaedbc2b611aa528f22343eb52db", data:web3.utils.sha3("totalSupply()")});
  if (call != '0x') {
    console.log('ERC20 token detected');
  } else {
    console.log('Not an ERC20 token address');
  }
}
checkAddress();
```

Comment: `with the single address it works fine` - what does that suppose to mean?

Comment: Side note: Not every contract which implements function `totalSupply` is an ERC20 contract.

Comment: @goodvibration Got it, however `totalsupply` is needed,

Comment: For "with the single address it works fine", single query with single address works fine, however multiple address query will always return an error

Comment: Why don't you share your `multiple address query` code then? If that is where the problem is, then we need to see it, don't you think? Also, be advised that you are calling `checkAddress` without `await`ing for it to complete. It will work fine as long as you don't do anything else after that (which depends on this function-call). But if you do several things (for example, calling it multiple times), then you may possibly need to `await` for each function call to complete. Without seeing your code, it would be difficult to know for sure.

Comment: @goodvibration Yes I have an await keyword and here is my code https://github.com/ethereumclassic/explorer/blob/636e0b99fbbf1c72cf71709368ee8b93b74ff6dc/tools/patcher.js#L149

Comment: Please post ONLY the code relevant for this question, and please post it HERE (not in a link).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check a few conditions with different ABIs:

1. Events `Transfer(address,address,uint256)` and `Approval(address,address,uint256)` should be emitted in case of any existing transactions to this smart contract
2. Methods `name()`, `symbol()` could return `bytes32` or `string`
3. Method `decimals()` could return `uint8` or `uint256`
4. Method `totalSupply()` should return `uint256`
5. Method `balanceOf(address)` should return `uint256` for any argument

Comment: The deployed EVM code does not have any metadata associated with it. You do not know what functions code entry point exposes to the transactions.

Comment: Furthermore your points 1, 2 and 3 are a bit incorrect: those are not required by the standard. (Yes, the event signatures are required but the standard doesn't require you to actually emit them)

Comment: @LauriPeltonen my answer contains the most practical recommendations, do you agree?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa you should form those ABIs on your own.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20 it is clearly stated in the standard that events MUST be fired on successful transfers and approvals.

Comment: Very well. In theory maybe yes they have to be emitted. But in practise it is impossible to know whether they are emitted by just looking at the bytecode. The standard cannot enforce actual implementation.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen events can be easily fetched using web3

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not exactly for your web3 needs but more of a generic answer. I asked a very similar question some time ago here: [How is a contract determined to be ERC20 compliant?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45431/how-is-a-contract-determined-to-be-erc20-compliant)

So, in the end, if the signatures are correct then it's considered an ERC20 contract. The actual implementation doesn't matter as long as the signatures are correct.

As for how to finding signatures from a deployed contract: as I see it you have two options:

1) Reverse-engineer the bytecode and try to find the signatures from there. This isn't necessarily possible or very easy: [How can you decompile a smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/188/how-can-you-decompile-a-smart-contract)

2) Issue all the relevant transactions (calling each ERC20 function) to the contract and see if they go through. This basically requires that you guess the ABI, part by part (it's easy enough to guess if it's ERC20 contract).

Comment: And how to verify the signatures? Using call method or something else?

Comment: Can you share me a code so I can understand?

Comment: Edited my answer to issue your questions. But not, I don't have any ready code available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an API it's dead simple. Amberdata's [`/addresses/:hash/information` endpoint](https://docs.amberdata.io/v1.0/reference/addresses#get-account-information) returns of list of contract types like so...

Request:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://web3api.io/api/v1/addresses/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d/information \
  --header 'x-api-key: <x-api_key>'
```

Response:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "title": "OK",
  "description": "Successful request",
  "payload": [
    { 
      "firstSeen": "2017-11-23T05:41:19.000Z",
      "type": "contract",
      "contractTypes": [
        "ERC721"      // <-- Here's what you are looking for
      ],
      "probability": 1,
      "network": {
        "name": "Ethereum",
        "network": "Mainnet",
        "slug": "ethereum-mainnet",
        "blockchainId": "1c9c969065fcd1cf",
        "link": "https://ethereum-mainnet.amberdata.io/addresses/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d"
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

This is the Cryptokitties address and as you can see it returns a contract type of `ERC712`.

If you have [an API key](https://amberdata.io/pricing) (it's free) you can try it out [here](https://docs.amberdata.io/v1.0/reference/addresses#get-account-information).